# Unbrick iPhone 3GS?

Tags: iphone, unlock

I have an iPhone 3GS running iOS 5 and baseband 5.16. After reading various blog posts and threads, I was told that in order to unlock it, I had to first upgrade it to the iPad baseband (6.15) and then downgrade it. Well, when I tried upgrading to 6.15, it took me halfway through the process and then said I had to first activate the iPhone. Not having a SIM card yet, I couldn't proceed. Now, WiFi doesn't work, Bluetooth doesn't work, calls, tons of things. The modem firmware is blank. The top left of the screen just says "Searching", and iTunes won't even recognize it. I think it may be bricked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your iPhone 3GS was not compatible with the iPad baseband ?

> The iPad baseband is not compatible with 3GS units manufactured week 34 of 2011 or later.  **If you have an iPhone3GS and if digits 3-5 of its Serial Number are 134 or later (xx134…), then you should NOT try to install the 06.15 baseband on your 3GS!**  It will brick your radio, preventing both the downgrade from working and normal iPhone software from using it as a phone!  Be warned!

See [this post](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/25350690843/0615-fun) on the iPhone Dev Team blog.